# Parsing recursive rules with spirit x3

Tags: c++, parsing, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I would like to parse the following recusive rule which parses simple template classe identifier like `foo<bar> foo<bar,baz> foo<bar<baz>>` here is the simple grammar:

```
identifier := A-Z | a-z | _
class_identifier = identifier ?("<" identifier|class_identifier 
                                    ( "," identifier|class_identifier)* 
                                ">")
```

I tried to write a parser with x3 like this:

```
 auto const identifier = x3::rule<class identifier_id, std::string>{"identifier"}
                          = +x3::char_("A-Za-z");

 x3::rule<class class_identifier, std::string> class_identifier = "class_identifier";

 auto const class_identifier_def  = identifier //classname
                                            >> -(x3::string("<")
                                                 >> (identifier | class_identifier)                                           
                                                 >> *(x3::string(",")                                                     
                                                      >> (identifier | class_identifier))
                                                 >> x3::string(">"));
 BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(class_identifier)
```

But this try fails to parse stuff like this `foo<bar<baz>>` but foo is fine.
Is there some logical error in my grammar or am I using boost spirit wrong since this is a recursive rule?

Comment: To make your life easier, I believe `(identifier | class_identifier)                                           
                                                 >> *(x3::string(",")                                                     
                                                      >> (identifier | class_identifier))` can be replaced with `(identifier | class_identifier) % x3::string(",")`. I wouldn't be surprised if that could be simplified to `% ','`, too, along with other places where a literal wouldn't interfere with operator overloading.

Comment: Indeed. `% ','` is fine

Comment: even if i parse into a string and want the `','` to be in the string?

Comment: @Exagon not then, indeed. There's an implicit `x3::omit[]` around the delimiter parser in the list operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found why this fails to parse. I hade to change this `(identifier | class_identifier)`  to this `(class_identifier | identifier)` because it also the `class_identifier` rule also starts with an `identifier`. thats why it tried to parse everytime with the `identifier` rule and then fails at the `<`

Comment: I think that currently the second branch of the alternative parser is never taken. I haven't tested it so I may be wrong but I'm pretty sure that you don't even need the alternative operator as long as you have the optional in `class_identifier`. If in the future you change the attributes (from a plain string to some kind of AST) your current definition would be better (removing that optional).